# ngrok tunnel hangs on windows

Tags: windows-10, tunnel

The setup has worked on a mac for a coworker, and I am trying to get it working with the same code/config within the same wifi network on windows.

Command

node_modules/ngrok/bin/ngrok.exe  http 8080

Hangs. No messages, nothing.

Windows firewall completely off (just to be sure). Running on Windows 10 pro. Terminal: git bash.

I have verified that I can access my computer on port 8080 from within internal network. Also verified that this setup works on a mac completely - so shouldn't be the router.

(I did mess with the router settings without success , and reverted.)

How do I get diagnostic information?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like ngrok is being bundled in a node module and the version of ngrok included there is unknown. You might try getting ngrok directly.

Further, diagnostic information can be viewed by turning on logging. This can be done by specifying the following in the global section of your ngrok configuration file:
log_level: info

There are several levels of logging available. You can learn more about logging in ngrok's documentation.

Answer (score 0):

there's might be a problem with console output.

for example, in my case, I was trying to run ngrok from Git Bash shell on Windows, which did a poor job on the output. everything seemed like it was stuck. on CMD it was okay